# What does 这一 mean in 在追求这一目标的过程中?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, measure-word

In the following sentence:

> 在追求**这一**目标的过程中，赛事转播和媒体是基本要素，国际足联与央视的合作伙伴关系发挥着至关重要的作用。

What does the 这一 here mean? I understand it modifies 目标, but does that mean 一 here works as a measure word for 目标？If that is true, what is the difference between 这一 and 这个, and why does it use 这一 here?

---

<sub>PS: Is the 着 in 发挥着 a [continuous aspect particle](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Aspect_particle_%22zhe%22)...?</sub>

Comment: CCG：２。９。when words like 这，那，每、某、哪，etc.  are used with numbers, they are placed before the numeral and measure word phrase. If the numeral is 一，it is usually dropped. 3.2. Note that 这 and 那 are always pronounced respectively as zhè and nà when used as demonstrative pronouns on their own. However, as demonstrative adjectives, when they are followed by a measure, they are also pronounced zhèi and nèi by many speakers. This is almost certainly a phonetic fusion of zhè + yī and nà + yī. Even when yī is present in its own right in an utterance, the pronunciation zhèi and nèi can still be used.

Comment: For example 这（一）件大衣 zhèi（yī）jiàn dàyī 那（一）天 nèi（yī）tiān。It also naturally follows that 这些 and 那些 are pronounced zhèixiē and nèixiē since the plural measure 些 xiē is itself used only with the measure 一 ＇yī＇。

Comment: 这一目标 means 这样(的)一个目标, literally translation: 这一目标, such a goal; 追求这一目标的过程中, in the process of pursuing such a goal.

Comment: 这一 means **such (a/an)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '一' here is for emphasis

- 在追求这目标的过程中 = In the process of pursuing this goal
- 在追求这(**一**)目标的过程中 = In the process of pursuing this (**one**/ **single**) goal

The two sentence basically have the same meaning, but the "一" in the second sentence emphasizes the singularity of the object 目标. Affirm it is the 'one' goal stated earlier and stress its importance.

More example:

此理想 = this goal

此一理想 = this one goal (affirm it is the 'one' goal stated earlier and stress its importance.  )

此人 = this person

此一人 =  this one person (stress the importance of this person in the context, for example, "this one person holds all the keys to your future success")

Comment: Thanks. In this case is it not correct to add the measure word, such as 这一个目标的过程中?

Comment: "此一" is a classical / literary term; "这一个" is modern and more colloquial term. You need to use classifier (in this case, 个) when you write 这一

Comment: In "在追求这一(个)目标的过程中" , the classifier is omitted, I suspect the writer mixed up "此一" and "这一个" , and wrote  an in-between word "这一" instead.

Answer (score 0):

literarily, 这一 is the best choice in 在追求这一目标的过程中, because 这一 connotes more and enlarge a vast of imaginations.

这一 could be interpreted as '这样一'，'这样一个'， '这一个',...

So, it connotes more than other variations: 这， 这个.

Comment: No,  '这一种' should  be shortened to "这种" ; "这样(的)一个" should  be "这样的"

Comment: Implications are not that strict. It's just how people feel it.

Comment: You can't interpret omitted element any way you want when the context clearly indicated what is omitted. '这一' can only mean '这一 + classifier' . For example : 这一案 can only mean 这一件案件, ( 'This case' , not 'this kind of case' ); 这一问 can only mean ' 这一个问题 ('this question'. not 'this kind of question')

Comment: "这一吻"  clearly means "这一(个)吻" --  same as "这一目标" clearly means "这一(个)目标"; No reasonable person would think 这一吻 could mean "这一种吻" or "这一目标" could mean "这一种目标"

Comment: I will remove the 这一种 if you don't like it, but my point 这一 implies more. 这一目标 could be like 这样一目标 or 像这样一个目标.

Comment: Find one person who would say   这样一目标 instead of  像这样的一个目标 or 这样的目标

Comment: That's my understanding anyway.